# Filter array object using $.grep failed

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
[{"id":1,"name":"John"},{"id":2,"name":"James"},{"id":3,"name":"Alex"}]

$.grep(Arr.nameList, function(e){ 
    return e.id != 1; 
});

console.log(Arr.nameList);
```

I expect to get 2 array returning back with John discard but I still get them all back, what's wrong with my `$.grep` above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.grep()` returns a new filtered array and does not affect the original array.

Try :

```
var filteredArray = $.grep(Arr.nameList, function(e){ 
    return e.id != 1; 
});    
console.log(filteredArray);
```

What you were doing was creating a new filtered array but ignoring it and inspecting the original un-affected array

Reference: [$.grep() docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xeds5Lm7/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: ah my careless mistake, tq!

Answer (score 1):

> **[jQuery.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) Description:** Finds the elements of an array which satisfy a filter function. The original array is not affected.

1. First you have to store the returned array in variable.
2. Remove `.nameList` you don't have to add anything just your array `Arr`.

**Replace :**

```
$.grep(Arr.nameList , function(e){ 
    return e.id != 1; 
});
```

**By :**

```
var result = $.grep(Arr , function(e){ 
    return e.id != 1; 
});
```

You can find the result of grep :

```
console.log(result);
```

Take a look at **[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eup8uoqv/8/)**.

Comment: that will completely replace the whole `Arr` object ... structure of which is not known

Comment: You are still making assumptions about `namelist` based on unknown information. `Arr` could be a big object with lots of properties